# ArcPy AddColormap method adds too many symbology values

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, symbology, colormap

I'm having an issue with trying to use a Colormap on my map that symbolizes plant hardiness zones. When I try to use `arcpy.management.AddColormap` to use a somewhat custom Colormap that I created and exported, it ends up having way too many symbols; there should be just 1-13, but it instead includes 0 and 14-255, all symbolized by the color black. The following picture is what I mean.

[image]

It's not affecting my map, but the symbology in the Drawing Order pane is now just a long mess. When I use the Add Colormap geoprocessing tool within ArcGIS Pro 3, this issue does not occur.

I tried to solve this by (using ArcPy) converting the colormap to Unique Values symbology, but then I get a different error, I think because Colormaps don't have built-in Symbology attributes.

Does anyone know why this is happening?

Code:

````py
import arcpy
from arcpy.sa import *

aprx = arcpy.mp.ArcGISProject("CURRENT")
aprxMap = aprx.activeMap
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

def reclass(param, out, clr):    
    arcpy.AddMessage('Beginning reclassification of minimum temperatures to plant hardiness zones.')
    arcpy.AddMessage('NOTE: For bioclimatic variables, bio_6 MUST be used or results have little meaning.')

    for lyr in param:
        desc = arcpy.Describe(lyr)
        if desc.isInteger == False:
            remap = RemapRange([[-51.1, -45.6, 1], [-45.6, -40.0, 2],
                                [-40.0, -34.4, 3], [-34.4, -28.9, 4], [-28.9, -23.3, 5],
                                [-23.3, -17.8, 6], [-17.8, -12.2, 7], [-12.2, -6.7, 8],
                                [-6.7, -1.1, 9], [-1.1, 4.4, 10], [4.4, 10, 11],
                                [10, 15.6, 12], [15.6, 21.1, 13]])
        else:
            remap = RemapRange([[-511, -456, 1], [-456, -400, 2],
                                [-400, -344, 3], [-344, -289, 4], [-289, -233, 5],
                                [-233, -178, 6], [-178, -122, 7], [-122, -67, 8],
                                [-67, -11, 9], [-11, 44, 10], [44, 100, 11],
                                [100, 156, 12], [156, 211, 13]])
        
        lyr_path = out+rf'\{lyr}_reclass.tif'

        new_reclass = Reclassify(lyr, 'Value', remap, 'NODATA')    
        new_reclass.save(lyr_path)
        arcpy.management.AddColormap(lyr_path, '#', clr)
        aprxMap.addDataFromPath(lyr_path)
        

if __name__ == '__main__':
    
    param = arcpy.GetParameter(0)
    out = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)
    clr = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(2)
    
    reclass(param, out, clr)```
````

Comment: Solved by replacing the 'NODATA' parameter in my Reclassify method with '#'. Not sure why this caused this issue.